# usermod question about option e

Tags: command-line, user-mode-linux

after reading the man pages I am unable to find an explanation of what this does (the tack e option)

usermod -L -e 1 username

-e 1

does this mean one day after the linux epoch, jan 1 1970? How would anyone know this since it's not documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It's value is in days.

From the [`usermod(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) man page:

> #### -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
>
> The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is specified in the format **YYYY-MM-DD**.

But there is more information in the [`shadow(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) man page:

> #### account expiration date
>
> The date of expiration of the account, expressed as the number of **days since Jan 1, 1970**.
>
> Note that an account expiration differs from a password expiration. In case of an acount expiration, the user shall not be
>   allowed to login. In case of a password expiration, the user is not
>   allowed to login using her password.
>
> An empty field means that the account will never expire.
>
> The value 0 should not be used as it is interpreted as either an account with no expiration, or as an expiration on Jan 1, 1970.

You can confirm this reading [the `usermod.c` source code](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/4.1.5.1/src/usermod.c#L928-L930):

```c
        case 'e':
            if ('\0' != *optarg) {
                user_newexpire = strtoday (optarg);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your guess is correct.

To verify it, you have to read the source-code:

- On my Debian machine, `dlocate` says that `usermod` is part of the `passwd` package.
- the `README` file in that package says the SVN repository can be browsed at http://svn.debian.org/wsvn/pkg-shadow/upstream
- in that repository, [src/usermod.c](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pkg-shadow/upstream/trunk/src/usermod.c?view=log) calls `strtoday` to process the option value for `-e` and
- `strtoday` is in [libmisc/strtoday.c](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pkg-shadow/upstream/trunk/libmisc/strtoday.c?view=log), with this comment:

```
    /* If a numerical value is provided, this is already a number of
     * days since EPOCH.
     */
```